# No se pudo encontrar imagen con CID en servicio windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicio

Estoy haciendo una prueba del envió de un correo con imágenes usando tag CID, realice una aplicación de escritorio que solo ejecute el correo,el programa me pidió colocarlas también en la carpeta debug del proyecto aparte de la carpeta donde las coloco, ahora el correo lo pase a un servicio windows pero me dice que

> No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\img.png'.

ya coloque la imagen en esa carpeta pero me sigue dando el mismo error, la imagen es tipo .png, este es mi codigo del correo

```html
   private void enviaMAil()
        {

            string htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
"<html xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
            "<head>" +
 "<meta http - equiv = 'Content-Type' content = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>" +
      "<title> Demystifying Email Design</title>" +
         "<meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body style = 'margin: 0; padding: 0;'>" +
  "<table align = 'center' border = '0' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' width = '900' > " +
                        "<tr>" +
         "<td align='left' bgcolor='#F8F8F8' style='padding: 15px 0 15px 0;border-bottom-width:6px;border-bottom-color:#225100;border-bottom-style:solid;'>" +
          " <img  src=\"cid:img\"' width='90' height='40'>" +
         "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
                         "<tr>" +
         "<td bgcolor = '#ffffff' style='padding:30px 30px 65px 30px'>" +
         "HOLAAA"+
          "</td>" +
         "</tr>" +
                          "<tr>" +
         "<td bgcolor = '#FFFFFF' align='center' style='padding: 15px 0 15px 0;border-top-width:1px;border-top-color:#FA5300;border-top-style:solid;'>" +           
          "</td>" +
         "</tr>" +
           "</table>" +
        "</body>" +
            "</html>";
            AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
               (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("img.png", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            inline.ContentId = "img";
            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);



            mail.From = new MailAddress("xx@xx.com");
            mail.To.Add("xx@xx.com");
            mail.Subject = "Alerta Estado Tags";
            mail.Body = inline.ContentId;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Credentials =
                    new NetworkCredential("xx@xx.com", "****"),
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 000,
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            smtp.Send(mail);
            mail.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Hace tiempo de igual forma me vi en la necesidad de adjuntar imágenes, me fue mas fácil ponerlas en drive con una ruta publica y eso poner en el HTML, digo por si estas buscando otra alternativa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la linea linkedResource se sustituyo por

```
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("C:\\img\\img.png", "image/jpeg");
```

indicandole la ruta `C:` y mi carpeta `img` donde se encuentran las imágenes